# Implementation of acts-as-messageable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, message

I'm using the gem acts-as-messageable and in my User controller i have

```
def inbox
  @title = "Inbox"
  @messages = current_user.received_messages
end

def outbox
  @title = "Outbox"
  @messages = current_user.sent_messages
end

def sendMessage
  @message = ActsAsMessageable::Message.new
end
```

Inbox and Outbox work correctly, however sendMessage is supposed to make a new message. In my views (sendMessage.html.erb) I have

```
<%= form_for(@message) do |f| %> 
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :to %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :to %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :topic %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :topic %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn primary">Send</button>&nbsp;<button type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button>
<% end %>
```

I have routed match "/sendMessage" => "users#sendMessage"
When I go to /sendMessage, however, i get this error: undefined method `acts_as_messageable_messages_path'